# Rear wheel air leakage while riding(royal enfield classic 350)

Tags: motorcycle, tires, wheels, royal-enfield

Air leakage on rear wheel while riding.The rear wheel got wheel wobbling from last five month onwards,Then i took into RE service center and  they did wheel alignment and changing swing arm bush. Even though issue is continues, then next service they suggested to change tyre and maintain the tyre pressure.After changing tyre also the issue not resolved.Then after noticed the rear wheel air reduced quickly while riding, if example rear tyre pressure filled  as 36/32 psi then after some kilometer it comes around 30/28 psi, any help to find the issue.

Comment: Poor seal of tire on rim, or dirty rims...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the classic 350 has tubeless tyres right? The inner tube or the valve stem might be leaking. If I'm wrong, and it does have tubeless tyres, it could be a bad seal of the tyre to the rim.

Answer (score -1):

The whole list of possible causes is:

- if a tubed tire, a leak in the tube itself
- leak or flaw in the valve stem or faulty valve core
- if a tubeless tire:

  ```
    a dirty or damaged rim which prevents the tire from sealing to the rim
    a crack in the rim which leaks air
    a puncture in the tire itself
  ```

The components must be examined carefully, as even a small hole can bleed air quickly.

Comment: This just repeats the other answer, with a bit of formatting...

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, but it also collects in one place the information previously offered in several. That may be of use to readers.

Comment: There is only ONE other answer...

Comment: The easiest thing to try would be to replace the valve core.  You can buy a bubble pack of them with the little installer tool to replace them at an auto parts store for 99 cents.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, there was only one Answer, but your comment also contained useful information: that the tire-rim seal might be impaired by dirt.